# How to handle Error props? (Error modal pops up only one time)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm showing 'error modal' when user tries to log in with incorrect credential. I'm checking whether my nextProps.errorMsg is undefined or not. If there is any error message, it shows error modal.

It only works at the first try. And I found componentWillReceiveProps didn't call when I set props.errorMsg from 'Can't Find Account' to ' ' or undefined.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // onAuthComplete Pass twice. so. it's
    console.log('yo');

    console.log(nextProps.errorMsg);
    if(nextProps.errorMsg) {
      this._showModal(); <<- here 
    }
    this.setState({isLoading:true});
    if (nextProps.hType==1 || nextProps.hType==2) {
      nextProps.navigation.navigate('Feed');
      this.setState({ password: ''})
    }
  }

_hideModal = () => {
    // empty error
    this.props.emptyErrorMsg;
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: false });
}
```

Here is my snippet of my reducers

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { token: null, errorMsg: undefined }
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    case AUTH_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { token: null, errorMsg: `Can't Find Account` };
    case EMPTY_ERROR_MSG:
      return { ...state, errorMsg: undefined}
}
```

And Actions

```
export const emptyErrorMsg = () => ({
  type: EMPTY_ERROR_MSG
})
```

Comment: Is that a `typho` that you have not called the func `this.props.emptyErrorMsg` ??

Comment: ??? I don't see a typho. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I'm using react-redux and dispatching emptyErrorMsg promise already. I'm little confused about your answer.

Comment: In `_hideModal` function you have not called the function `this.props.emptyErrorMsg` is that a typho or the actual issue ?

Comment: `this.props.emptyErrorMsg()`

Comment: In my understanding, emptyErrorMsg works same as emptyErrorMsg(). It both pass null as a parameter by React default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pointed out in a comment that

```
    this.props.emptyErrorMsg;
```

and

```
    this.props.emptyErrorMsg();
```

both execute the function emptyErrorMsg.
This is **not** the case. Here is the difference:

```
const yourFunction = this.props.emptyErrorMsg;
yourFunction();
this.props.emptyErrorMsg();
```

`this.props.emptyErrorMsg` returns a pointer to the function itself. It doesn't get executed. You can assign the function to a constant and execute the constant later (`yourFunction()`).

`this.props.emptyErrorMsg()` executes the function. This is probably what you wanted to do in your function _hideModal().